# unrecognized expression from JSp page

Tags: jquery, html

```
<a href="/userinfo/edituser" title="Header" data-toggle="tab">Click Me</a><br>
```

I am using above link in spring jsp page. But its throwing an `unrecognized expression: /userinfo/edituser`

But if I removed data-toggle attribute then its working fine.

I am very new with this exception.

Why its throwing this exception?

For Example I am using below as demo example but it also throwing an exception:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="http//google.com" title="Header" data-toggle="tab">Click Me</a><br>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure with the link ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the above link in JSP page

Comment: can you paste that jsp code where you using it

Comment: Please check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

First, if you use data-toggle, specify `href="#"`, otherwise it's quite meaningless.

Second, your data-toggle is tab, but you use popover in JS.

Third, this is completely unrelated to JSP, as you don't have one line of it in the example.

Here's a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover">Click Me</a><br>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are correct, its not related to JSP. Your example also correct, but I need to use link instead of '#' in href link.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty, but what is the meaning of having a popover if you are using a link. The popover will only show upp briefly befor the user is sent to the link page.

Comment: I dont need popover . Please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

`http//google.com` link is incorrect by the way.You can try directly on your browser and check. Secondly it doesn't even require a link when you using `popover();`

Correct syntax would be

```
<a href="www.google.com" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" 
data-content="yoyo">Click Me</a>
```

`href` should be to the current page.

Its output is like this

[image]

If you are looking for tabs go through this [**demo**](https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo/)

.